# Opening text file by using push button in Qt

Tags: qt, signals-slots

what should be the contents in the area of signal and slots of the push button in the Qt, so that after clicking the push button only the text file will open.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
 {
 ....
 }
```

Comment: You can find examples on how to read a text file in Qt docs: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfile.html

Comment: What do you mean by "opening" a text file? Describe exactly what you want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever you want in order to open file, like FILE, fstream, QFile ecc. You simply call a class method, but inside that function you can put everything.
You're using Qt, so you can check QFile class of QT.

Comment: I tried by using                                                 QFile file("in.txt");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return;

    while (!file.atEnd()) {
        QByteArray line = file.readLine();
        process_line(line);
    }                                                                 but error is coming as error: 'process_line' was not declared in this scope

Comment: @Latik `process_line()` is a dummy function name that you have to write yourself. Replace that line with anything you need to process the text line.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

        QFile file( filename );

        if( !file.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text ) )
            QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("Error opening!"), tr("Could not open the file"));

        QTextStream stream( &file );

        while( !stream.atEnd() )
        {
            QString lineText;
            lineText = stream.readLine(); //Read a line of text

            QStringList tokens= lineText.split(" ",QString::SkipEmptyParts); //Take tokens from the line
        }

        file.close();
}
```

Comment: I tried using your code but it is giving warning as: Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: (null). And after clicking the push button nothing is happening.

Comment: It does nothing. It is only a sample to show how to read a text file.